# Auto loading and disposing image gallery

Tags: android, dynamic, image-gallery

I need to make an image gallery that takes a JSON list of remote images and pre-loads them and disposes them on the fly as i scroll left or right. I cannt seem to find any examples of this other than a list of images being loaded on the fly. What I want to do is to load the next ones (left and right) while the previous one is on the screen, dumping the others as I go.

I see widget.gallery but is this suitable for this or should I use a `Canvas` and write my own?

Answer (score 0):

Look at here. There is a `ListView` with lazy loading, this should show you the solution.

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)